# SQLDataReader bugging while using .Nest() or .Read()

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sqldatareader

I'm retrieving some information from an MSSQL via SQLDataReader, but while debugging it I notice in some cases the reader clears the result view with the error "Enumeration yielded no results" see the screenshot 
[Before Running passing Read(),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTLs5.jpg)

[After passing read()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bjVv.jpg)



 this is my code,the error happens on getActiveUsers() method. 
getDatabases() works just fine. **could someone help me?** cheers

```
 public partial class automation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    static List<ActiveUsers> activeUsers = new List<ActiveUsers>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxGridView1.DataSource = activeUsers.ToList();

    }
    public List<ActiveUsers> getDatabases()
    {

        //passing query
        string SqlQuery = "SELECT [WorkspaceName],[MaConfig_Customers].Name  FROM [MaConfig_CustomerDatabases] INNER JOIN [MaConfig_Customers] ON [MaConfig_CustomerDatabases].CustomerId = [MaConfig_Customers].CustomerId where [MaConfig_Customers].Status = 0";
        //creating connection
        string sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MaxLiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlconn);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         List<ActiveUsers> results = new List<ActiveUsers>();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ActiveUsers company = new ActiveUsers();
                company.DatabaseName = String.Format("{0}", reader["WorkspaceName"]);
                company.ClientName = String.Format("{0}", reader["Name"]);
                results.Add(company);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        return results;
    }

    public void getActiveUsers()
    {

        activeUsers.Clear();
        List<ActiveUsers> Databases= getDatabases();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        string SqlQuery = "select [disabled], [ADMN_Users1].[Record_Id] ,[ADMN_Users].[User_Id] from admn_Users1  inner join [ADMN_Users] on [ADMN_Users1].[record_Id] = [ADMN_Users].[Record_Id] Where [disabled] & 0x2 = 0 ";

        for (int i = 0;i < Databases.Count;i++)
        {

            conn.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=MAXSQLCLUS01;" +
            "Initial Catalog=" + Databases[i].ToString()+";"+
            "User id=sa;" +
            "Password=Max1m1zer;";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int NumberOfUsersCounter = 0 ;
            //TODO Select Enabled users
            if (reader.Read())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string user = String.Format("{0}", reader["User_Id"]);
                    //logic to remove system users

                    if (user.Equals("master", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {


                    }
                    else
                    if (user.Equals("emailuser", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    if (user.Equals("webuser", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        NumberOfUsersCounter++;
                    }

                }
                ActiveUsers newEntry = new ActiveUsers();

                newEntry.NumberActiveUsers = NumberOfUsersCounter.ToString();
                newEntry.DatabaseName = Databases[i].DatabaseName.ToString();
                newEntry.ClientName = Databases[i].ClientName.ToString();
                activeUsers.Add(newEntry);

            }
            conn.Close();

            //Add to ActiveUsers list


        }



        ASPxGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        ASPxGridView1.DataSource = activeUsers.ToList();
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        getActiveUsers();
    }

    protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
        ASPxGridViewExporter1.Landscape = true;
        ASPxGridViewExporter1.FileName = "User Count Report";
        ASPxGridViewExporter1.WriteXlsToResponse();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: An unrelated bug: You are skipping the first result. `if (reader.Read()) { while(reader.Read()) {...`. Remove the enclosing `if`, all it does is see if there is a row and retrieve it but then you do not read it, instead you do it again in the if so the first result is always discarded.

Comment: As the screen warns you -- expanding will enumerate the enumerable. An `SqlDataReader` can only be enumerated once, since it only reads the database once. Don't look at it with the debugger unless you're OK with having to restart the debugging session.

Comment: Another side note: `company.DatabaseName = String.Format("{0}", reader["WorkspaceName"])` would be better written as `company.DatabaseName = reader.GetString(0)`. The same goes for the next line. No need to use `string.Format` and you are specifying the columns and order in the query so use the ordinal index so get the native value.

Comment: i will try what you suggested @Igor

Comment: Side note 3: Finally I would recommend you wrap the `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` in `using` blocks to ensure they are closed/disposed after use even in the event of an exception.

Comment: @Igor yes yes ofc. by the way, removing the IF solved the issue.

Comment: As an aside, while manually writing loops to suck the brains out of `SqlDataReader`s makes for fast results, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) is almost as fast and a lot more convenient.

Comment: Side Note 4: Create Static connection strings if possible and use it by switch case statements based on database. This will help connection pooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are skipping the first result. `if (reader.Read()) { while(reader.Read()) {....` Remove the enclosing if, all it does is see if there is a row and retrieve it but then you do not read it, instead you do it again in the if so the first result is always discarded.

```
public List<ActiveUsers> getDatabases()
{
    //passing query
    string SqlQuery = "SELECT [WorkspaceName],[MaConfig_Customers].Name  FROM [MaConfig_CustomerDatabases] INNER JOIN [MaConfig_Customers] ON [MaConfig_CustomerDatabases].CustomerId = [MaConfig_Customers].CustomerId where [MaConfig_Customers].Status = 0";
    //creating connection
    string sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MaxLiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using(con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlconn))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<ActiveUsers> results = new List<ActiveUsers>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ActiveUsers company = new ActiveUsers();
                company.DatabaseName = reader.GetString(0);
                company.ClientName = reader.GetString(1);
                results.Add(company);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Side notes:

- `company.DatabaseName = String.Format("{0}", reader["WorkspaceName"])` would be better written as `company.DatabaseName = reader.GetString(0)`. The same goes for the next line. No need to use `string.Format` and you are specifying the columns and order in the query so use the ordinal index so get the native value.
- I would recommend you wrap the `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` in `using` blocks to ensure they are closed/disposed after use even in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       ActiveUsers company = new ActiveUsers();
       company.DatabaseName = String.Format("{0}", reader["WorkspaceName"]);
       company.ClientName = String.Format("{0}", reader["Name"]);
       results.Add(company);
    }
}
```

use this

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       ActiveUsers company = new ActiveUsers();
       company.DatabaseName = String.Format("{0}", reader["WorkspaceName"]);
       company.ClientName = String.Format("{0}", reader["Name"]);
       results.Add(company);
    }
}
```

your if Condition is wrong

```
if(reader.Read()) ==> is Wrong
```

Read() is not return boolean Value

use HasRows to check rows in SQLDataReader